# .Net and Ruby on Rails - use situations

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, programming-languages

I only want facts as far as possible. There are some things that ASP.Net does more quickly and easily than Ruby on Rails. I simply want to find out in which situations you would use ASP.Net, and which RoR handles better. So, given that you have a team that is equally as good at RoR and ASP.Net, where would you choose each technology? The obvious ones for ASP.Net are:

- Within a Windows Server company, ASP.Net is king.
- When you need to use Web References, Visual Studio and MonoDevelop are second to none.
- If you are desperate about speed, C#'s compiled nature would probably be faster or more efficient - please, if this isn't true, let me know.
- When it comes to a CMS, Umbraco on .Net seems to be better than the RoR offerings. Again, if I'm wrong, please let me know!
- If using SQL Server or Sharepoint, then it's extremely likely that .Net will be the better choice.

However, RoR would be better on:

- A Linux server
- Prototyping and smaller data-driven applications

I'm really worried that this question will get closed, but I really do need to know the answer to this question for my job. I'm now leading a few guys that default to Ruby on Rails for new apps but has a lot of experience in ASP.Net too, so I want to know that I'm making the right decision as far as a project-by-project basis comes along, and not just 'this feels "enterprisey", let's go ASP.Net'. If I can ask it in a different exchange, that would be great. I do understand that for the most part, both will be the same. The HTML/CSS/Javascript set does most of the work here, and this is the only choice I need to make, so I need to know I'm making the best possible for the upcoming situations.

If there's an article that addresses this, please point me in that direction, I've tried googling to no real effect. Thank you for any help that you can give me.

tl;dr: What situations suit the .Net stack and development workflow better than RoR, and vica versa.

Thanks again!

Comment: To me, it's basically equivalent to the OS choice. If I use Windows - it's ASP.NET. But I gave up on microsoft technologies long ago, so now it's always rails on linux. Easy choice :-)

Comment: As for "it's **so** much easier to write a blog engine in X" kind of arguments, I think there are none. Both technologies are pretty capable (since  asp.net stole many things from rails :-) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my 2 cents on this subject, but first of all let me make a quick disclaimer.

I used to work with ASP.net for about 3 years and have recently started leading a small team developing a web application in Rails.
At the moment I must say I am very biased towards RoR, but I'll try to give an objective review.

### ASP.net

I would go with ASP.net for a few things:

- Larger, data-heavy applications, rather than small and agile applications;
- Applications oriented for medium-large companies working with Windows;
- Very simple projects (if you're working with entry-level developers).

For the following reasons:

- ASP.net's compiled nature makes it a great "data-pusher", that is, dealing with large datasets or performing costly operations.
- Windows is the OS of choice in practically every medium-large organization I've ever seen, and *Windows Servers* are often accompanied.
- Microsoft's involvement is exceptional (See [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)'s profile as an example).
- The *IIS-MSSQL-ASP-VS* bundle is a very "tightly-coupled" development suite, both in compatibility between its parts and in support.
- Microsoft support (I'm no authority on this, but I'm guessing being a paying customer gives you some official support).
- Entity Framework is a good and *very* easy-to-use ORM.
- Shallow learning curve, and plenty of courses, therefore good for entry-level developers.

### Ruby on Rails

I'd go with RoR for the following:

- Any project requiring quick prototyping or running a tight schedule for a proof-of-concept (i.e: Start-up companies);
- Small-medium web applications;
- Any project with a small budget.

And here's why:

- Development on Rails is the fastest I've seen, compared ASP.net and even PHP.
- **Gems**. There are a lot of things that are a pain to code in ASP.net and are solved simply on Rails with gems (Pagination, tree structures, ordered lists just to name a few).
  Also, things like [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) and [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) are *huge* time-savers and practically built-in.
- *Open-source*, thus often requiring a smaller budget.
- *Easy deployment*. Many of Rails' features take deployment into consideration (database seeding, migrations, etc.). I found ASP.net project much harder to deploy.
- *NoSQL* is much more common with Rails, and I assume better supported.
- Rails' ActiveRecord is an excellent and easy-to-use ORM.
- Brilliant community.

**However**, it is worth noting that on many terms, both Rails and ASP.net MVC have a lot in common and often equivalent.

*MySQL* and *MSSQL* are both enterprise-level databases and both *IIS* and *Apache* are enterprise-level web servers.
You can find large websites running ASP.net and Rails (i.e: StackOverflow on .NET, [Github and more](http://rubyonrails.org/applications) on Rails), and both can deliver performance and scalability.
Both have support of 3rd party tools, such as MongoDB and Memcached through gems or external libraries.

In conclusion, it is my opinion that your considerations should take more into account the final deployment environment, ease of development, schedule, and the overall preference of your developers and peers than the technological differences between the two frameworks.

Comment: "I found ASP.net project much harder to deploy" - ASP.net has '1-click deploy' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of getting hammered I'll jump in and give an answer.  If you're application is going to do the heavy lifting with CSS/HTML/JS then I'd probably go RoR (not that it can't handle data and throughput, it can) if you feel comfortable with the hosting environment necessitated by the choice.  It's light weight and there are a lot of tool sets available to make it run without need a lot of intervention on a regular basis.  On the other hand, if your IT support/operations is a Windows shop and the thought of having a *nix box in their midst makes them shudder then the smart choice is probably ASP.NET MVC on Windows Server.  I'm going to assume you and your teammates are smart.  You figure things out.  You can figure out RoR and be productive because by nature you are problem solvers.  It just depends on what your environmental friction could be, among other things.

Comment: I'll also add that if you figure out RoR, figuring out .Net MVC should be a fair breeze as well.  I haven't played with it since 1.0, and certainly it's more mature now.

Answer (score 0):

We could discuss trough hours which one to use, and right now you have the possibility to use asp.net MVC Framework as well. But in the end the two are MVC frameworks.

So I googled some articles for you, maybe they can help in your decisions:

http://blog.approache.com/2010/11/ruby-on-rails-vs-aspnet-mvc.html

http://rubysource.com/putting-ruby-rails-c-and-asp-net-in-context/

http://rubysource.com/why-should-a-net-developer-look-into-ruby-or-ruby-on-rails/

http://rubysource.com/switching-to-ruby-from-net/

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/what-asp-net-mvc-can-do-and-ruby-on-rails-cant

http://lassala.net/2011/05/05/ruby-on-rails-or-asp-net-mvc/

So as you mentioned in your post, you and the guys have a lot of experience in programming asp.net, so I think you could make work your project either in ROR or MVC. At this point it is only depends on your appetite to experience.

Comment: Thank you for these, I've read a few already, but a couple I'd missed, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My reason for choosing rails over .net is different than the answers I've seen here. The MAIN reason I choose to use rails for every project is because **I ENJOY programming on the rails stack MUCH MORE than on the .net stack. It's just more FUN**. You could say that when considering performance, support, costs, ease of development, etc they both come out about even. So my deciding factor was ENJOYMENT.

I'm pretty biased towards rails but just to give you quick background, I worked as a web dev on the MS stack from 1996 to 2009. I used asp.net up to MVC 1.0 but never tried .net mvc 2.0  because that was about the time I tried rails (version 3.0 had just come out). I used .net mvc for about a year. After that I tried rails for about 2 months and decided at that point to go fully with rails.

And this might be considered anecdotal but I see MANY people jump from .net to ruby/rails and then rave about rails. Some popular people include Rob Connery and Roy Osherov. It's a lot more rare to see people go from rails to .net and rave about .net. Actually, I have never seen that.